# Plotting multiple radius values for single theta

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot points in a polar grid, but I don't know how to plot multiple points for a single theta value. I have a float type for theta that goes from 0 to 90 degrees split into 90 evenly spaced intervals:

```
import numpy as np
theta = np.linspace(0,np.pi/2,90)
```

And then I have a list of various r or radius values generated by the following loop:

```
i = 100
initialR = 0.32130341
radiusList = []
for y in range(i):
    radius = pow(1.02,y)*initialR
    radiusList.append (float(radius))
```

What I want is for a given theta value, say theta = pi/2 for it to plot points at every radius value. Is there a simple way to do this? I am planning on using matplotlib pyplot scatter, but don't know if there is a better option? I feel like it should be straight forward, but I haven't found any plots where the theta and r vary in size.

Comment: Yes -- just be appending to a list of `theta` in the same loop as you build `radiusList`.

Comment: Yes, sorry I am using matplotlib scatter plot! @RoryDaulton

Comment: Are you committed to using matplotlib's `scatter`, or will [polar](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.polar.html) suffice? You may want to look at [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-polar-scatter-py) for making a scatter plot on a polar coordinate system.

Comment: I don't want to append to the list of theta, that would just give me a really long list. Can you please clarify? @Linuxios

Comment: @RoryDaulton yes, I have looked at that example already. I think my issue is that I just don't know how to get my data in the proper format so theta and r are the same size.

Comment: @summer: Build the list of `theta` as you build the list of radii. That way you can repeat `theta` values as you need.

Comment: I do not understand your difficulty. You could plot just one value of theta and multiple values of r. Just repeat the value as often as you need it, as in `[theta] * n`. You could do this as often as you want before you show the graph. Perhaps you should show a full example of what you want, not just the partial example you show now.

Comment: If the repetition pattern of `theta` is fairly consistant, though, just use something like `np.repeat` or `np.tile`.

Comment: @RoryDaulton that is pretty much the code, all that is missing is the plotting which doesn't work anyways the way my data is written. I will try to work with the help you have given, thank you!

Comment: @Linuxios Ok I see, I will give that a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your second block of code can be vectorized as:

```
np.power(1.02, np.arange(i))*initialR
```

It this what you are trying to get?

```
thetas = np.linspace(0,np.pi/2,10)
i = 100
initialR = 0.32130341
radii = np.power(1.02, np.arange(i))*initialR

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
for theta in thetas:
    plt.plot(np.full(radii.shape, theta), radii)
```

[image]

EDIT: drawing single points instead of a line:

```
thetas = np.linspace(0,np.pi/2,10)
i = 100
initialR = 0.32130341
radii = np.power(1.02, np.arange(i))*initialR

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
for theta in thetas:
    plt.plot(np.full(radii.shape, theta), radii, 'o', mfc='none')
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you! This is very similar to what I am trying to get, rather I would like it to be individual points for each r value instead of a solid line, but very close.

Comment: Since you are plotting 100 `r` values, the points will tend to overlap and merge to form one line anyway, see my edit above. Also notice that I've only plotted 10 `theta` values instead of 90, the result will be even more of a mess of points

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect!

Comment: One last question, so I better understand the solution if you wouldn't mind helping me out a little more, what do the plt.subplot arguments do? For example, the subplot_kw statement, what does that mean? And what does radii.shape do exactly?

Comment: `plt.subplots()` is a command that can create a figure and one or several subplots in one line, I use it mainly by convenience. To create polar plot , you need to pass the instruction `projection='polar'` when the subplot is created, that the function of `subplot_kw`. Please read the documentation https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots

Comment: `radii.shape` returns the shape of the array, in this case it is a vector of 100 elements, so `(100,)`. Passing that to `np.full()` creates an array with the same shape. Again, see the documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html